# Theory of Transfinite Numbers (Georg Cantor)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would appreciate if someone could help me understand how the author, Georg Cantor, arrived at the three conclusions in the second to last line of page 96: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/cantor1.pdf

The three conclusions are:

{$t_{2v-1}$} ~ {$s_v$}

{$t_{2v}$} ~ {$t_v$}

$X_1$ ~ $X_1$

Thank you!

Comment: It might be helpful if you copy the three conclusions you are having problems with into the question's text.  Do you mean [487](5),[487](6) and [487](7) ? Or something to do with [488].  It would be clearer if you just wrote out the conclusions rather then make reference to them.

Comment: Thanks. I am referring to [488]. I'll write the conclusions.

Comment: Bot $\{ t_v \}$ and $\{ s_v \}$ are *enumerable* totalities (or aggregetes): thus, they are equipotent (their cardinality is $\aleph_0$). And obviously $X_1$ is equipotent with itself.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation; however, I think that the symbol, ~, refers to equating "aggregetes" rather than cardinality. How are the aggregetes equal if their units or constituents are different? I think the units are different because the subscripts are different.

Comment: The symbol means "equivalence"; see [482]: "we say that two aggregates $M$ and $N$ are "equivalent" if it is possible to put them ...".